# Jenkins “Keep this build forever” button is missing

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am an admin on our Jenkins master but, this button is not available for any builds for any user.

I found this question which has a somewhat relevant answer since we are also using Matrix-based security, however no one has this button showing up on any build

Is there a plugin required to have this feature available?

[image: What each build looks like]

My version isJenkins ver. 2.105

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Keep forever option appears only when relevant, meaning only if you opt in on other option `Discard old builds`. If not it's irrelevant see [jenkins users answer](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/How-to-mark-builds-quot-keep-forever-td381135.html)

> option only appears if you have chosen to Discard Builds 
>   from the config for the job. (i.e. if you have chosen not to discard 
>   any builds have a certain time/build number, then the button won't 
>   show).

Comment: I do have Discard old builds set on almost of my jobs

Comment: NVM we had a plugin that is also called Discard old builds which was configured. I see now there is a built-in option for Discard old builds. the button shows up with that option applied.